# (proto-)Germanic evidence for Late Latin vowel length

Tags: phonology, historical-linguistics, latin, romance-languages, proto-germanic

I would like to find a list of borrowings illustrating the reflexes in (proto-)Germanic of Latin long and short vowels. In particular I would like to find substantiation to the standard claim that it reflects long and short vowels differently. This statement would be correct in relation to qualitatively distinct pairs such as *v**i**det* != *v**ī**dit* that in most of Romance likewise remain distinct, but the pairs that in North-Western Late Latin/proto-Romance must be described as contrasting primarily in terms of length are the vowels of *v**i**r* and *v**ē**r*, and these ultimately merge with the rise of Open Syllable Lengthening.

Here's an example of the kind of evidence I'm looking for, from [Stifter 2009](http://mural.maynoothuniversity.ie/4645/1/DS_Proto.pdf):

> In words that were borrowed into Germanic or its dialects from Latin
>   in the imperial period, Lat. ā is not reflected by *ō but by the new *ā
>   by default, e.g. OHG phāl 'stake' <- pālus, OHG strāzza 'street' <- strāta, OHG kāsi 'cheese' <- cāseus, the OHG agentive suffix -āri <- ārius. Cases where Lat. ā seems to be reflected by Gmc. *ӑ are actually borrowings from Vulgar Latin with pretonic shortening, e.g. OHG ratih, retih 'radish' <- VLat. rӑdīc- < Lat. rādīx 'root'.

I would like some sort of a reference - if not a dedicated discussion then at least a list of borrowings - showing in which environments and at what periods of borrowing the Late Latin vowel length contrast between **/a/** and **/ā/**, **/į/** and **/ē/**, **/ę/** and **/ae/**, **/ų/** and **/ō/**, and perhaps **/ǫ/** and **/au/** is reflected in Germanic languages.